# Undefined HTMLInput Element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am currently working on a web page but I can't seem to get the username value, I've been following a tutorial on "ng-book" and it works fine there but when I try to do the same in my app it won't work.

**signup.component.html**

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-content">  
        <div *ngIf="!next"> <!-- hide inputs after a click -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="" placeholder="Username" name="username" #username>
</div> </div> </div> 
<button type="button" class="btn rounded-btn"  *ngIf="!next" (click)="validateNext(username)"> Next </button> 
</form>
```

I have more inputs, but I tried to make it as simple as possible.

**signup.component.ts**

```
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
signUp: SignUp;
next: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.signUp = new SignUp();
    }

    validateNext(username: HTMLInputElement) : boolean {
        console.log("works");
        var should = this.signUp.validateNext(username, username, username); //password, confirmPassword);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**signup.model.ts**

```
export class SignUp {
username: string;

validateNext(username: HTMLInputElement, password: HTMLInputElement, confirmPassword: HTMLInputElement) : boolean {
    var result: boolean = false;

    this.username = username.value;
    console.log(this.username);
    return false;
}
```

**Error**

```
SignupComponent.html:69 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at SignUp.validateNext (signup.model.ts:21)
at SignupComponent.validateNext (signup.component.ts:23)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SignupComponent.html:70)
```

Comment: `*ngIf` un-renders the element when the condition is false. the `[hidden]` directive will hide the element (display: none) when the condition is true. so your HTMLInput does not exist because it is not rendered at the time of the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `[hidden]` instead of `ngIf` :

```
<div [hidden]="next"> <!-- hide inputs after a click -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="" placeholder="Username" name="username" #username>
</div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer but @LLai explanation made it a lot easier to understand why.